# How can I pipe emails to my Laravel 5 application

Tags: php, laravel-5, email

I'm currently using cPanel on my server side and i've tried all the tutorials online that show how to pipe all your emails to Laravel project, I did find one tutorial that works on Laravel 4 but unfortunately it didn't work for me on Laravel 5.0:

http://www.sitepoint.com/piping-emails-laravel-application/

I've set up my cPanel "default address" to a php handler file but since i'm working with Laravel I can't get this file to work with the app classes and do stuff for my customers (like send notifications, save email information on the database, etc...)
please let me know if there is a nice clean way to accomplish that.

BTW, I need all the emails on this domain to go to my php handler not from one address only, because each one of my customers got his own email address

Comment: you should use queues, here is a nice tutorial (http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues)

Comment: to be more specific, I would like to call a command in my laravel application every time a new email came in with my domain extension and based on that I will do something with that information... the tutorial is great but not what i'm looking for

Comment: Any luck on this OP? I'm looking for a solution too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up creating a free account on mandrill and they are posting all my incoming emails to one of my routes.. than, I've created a controller to handle the incoming emails from mandrill and i can do whatever I need in there...Thats the best way to do It...I'm getting and processing emails in less than 2 seconds. That's amazing.

I've added the mandrill MX records to a subdomain of mine and now I gave all my customers an email address with this subdomain on it "username@inbox.mydomain.com"

This is my route:

```
Route::post('inbound/message', 'MailController@inboundMessages');
```

and this is my controller example:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class MailController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * main function to receive incoming email from mandrill POST request
     * @param  JSON $request Mandrill Object in JSON format
     * @return string
     */
    public function inboundMessages(Request $request){
        if(isset($request['mandrill_events'])){

           $messageJson = json_decode($request['mandrill_events']);
           $message = $messageJson[0]->msg;
           $email = [
             "to" => $message->email,
             "from" => $message->from_email,
             "name" => isset($message->from_name) ? $message->from_name : "No Name",
             "subject" => isset($message->subject) ? $message->subject : "No Subject",
             "content" => isset($message->text) ? $message->text : "",
             "content_html" => isset($message->html) ? $message->html : ""
          ];

          //do whatever you want with your $email

        }
    }

}
```

hope it helps :) Good luck